# javascript code to php?

Tags: php, javascript

How do I write the following javacript code in php:

```
var ShareImageIdVar = location.href.match(/\d+/);
```

there is a number in the url that I want to store it in the variable `ShareImageIdVar`.

an example of a possible url:

```
http://www.mysite.com/5.php
http://www.mysite.com/41.php
http://www.mysite.com/547.php
http://www.mysite.com/2145.php
```

Comment: Check out `preg_match`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: I do not know anything about php and I only want to do this small part.

Comment: @user1200640: Then you should learn at least that small part rjz mentioned.

Comment: Could you post one (maybe a few) examples of what the url might look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you js code is identify the first numerical string from all string

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var str = 'adsdf12323sad678jhgj';
var ShareImageIdVar = str.match(/\d+/);
alert(ShareImageIdVar);
</script>
```

try this in PHP

```
$string = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$number = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', $string);
```

thanks

Comment: This is perfectly workings sir, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for the PHP equivalent of your JS code, I can see why some would use regex (preg_match/preg_replace). However, there are better ways of getting the file name of the current script.

Based on the examples you gave, something like this would actually be more logical:

```
$file = explode('.', basename(__FILE__));
$ShareImageIdVar = $file[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$address = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
preg_match('/\d+/', $address, $ShareImageIdVar );
echo $ShareImageIdVar[0];
```